# How to rewrite internal URLs in AEM using resource mapping (etc/map)

Tags: url-rewriting, aem, url-shortener

I wanted to rewrite my page URLs from `localhost:4502/content/myappname/en/home.html` to `localhost:4502/home.html`

I tried using resource mapping and it worked. But when viewed the page source, other hyperlinks present in the page still contains `content/myappname/en/` in their URL.

My doubt is if only the page which I'm accessing will have shortened URL and other hyperlinks(redirecting to other pages) in the page also gets their URLs shortened.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the resource mapping helps for the URL conversion when you request the resource. For the internal links, take a look at the AEM link rewriter: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem63_link_rewriter.html